# Add click event on a dynamically created element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to add a click event on an element which i create dynamically in Vanilla JS. With jquery its super simple all i would do is

```
$(document).on('click','.el', function() {
    //somecode 
})
```

However with Vanilla JS (because i'm using react) i can't do the same thing.
I've tried adding the dynamic element as an argument just like i would in jquery but no money.

I'm sure it can be done just not the way i'm thinking. Any ideas?

I tried

```
let div = document.createElement('DIV')
div.classList.add('el')
document.addEventListener('click','.el', function() {
    //some code
})
```

I also tried

```
document.addEventListener('click',div, function() {
    //some code
})
```

None of these methods worked

Comment: try `div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //some code
})`

Comment: Is it possible to update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of how you are generating elements? If you have the raw htmlDOMNode you can add a listener to that.

Comment: See the working solution below in my answer. Would you mind accepting any answer. if its helped you ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.classList.add(".whatever");
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('dynamic elements')
});
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yu1kchLf/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use and `onclick` function and just call it as `variable` from your `dynamically` added elements.

**Live Demo**

```js
//Create function
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.classList.add("myBtn");
button.innerText = 'Click Me';
button.onclick = myFunction //assign a function as onclick attr
document.body.appendChild(button);


//Call function
function myFunction() {
  console.log('I am being called from dynamically created button')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are missing is appending the element you created to your DOM.
have a look at this:

```
var createDiv = function() {
  let div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.id = 'el';
  div.innerHTML = '<b>hey</b>';
  div.classList.add('styles');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Look here');
  })
};
```

here's a fiddle so you can playaround: https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/e6wrLnj9/32/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```js
const d=document.getElementById("container");
document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target?.classList.contains('el')) { 
   console.log("My .el element was clicked!");
   ev.target.classList.contains("segundo") && 
   (d.innerHTML+='<p class="el">another clickable paragraph</>');
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container"><h2>Something unclickable</h2>
<p class="el primero">A clickable paragraph!</p>
<p class="otro primero">something unclickable again ...</p>
<button class="el segundo">add clickable element</button>
</div>
```

The event handler is attached to the document itself but will only fire the `console.log()` if the `ev.target`, i. e. the clicked element, is of class "el".